# How to make footer sticky with Halfmoon?

Tags: html, css, eleventy, halfmoon

I'm trying to make a footer sticky with halfmoon but I see nothing in the documentation and I cannot find anything online.

I would like to achieve sticky footer like this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Layout_cookbook/Sticky_footers

On my website it looks like this instead : https://mogeret.ee/posts/2020-10-16-rocket11ty-first-release/ Not sticky at all !

Here's the base layout I use

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Meta tags -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
  <!-- SEO -->
  <title>{{ title or metadata.title }}</title>
  <meta name="title" content="{{ title or metadata.title }}">
  <meta name="description" content="{{ description or metadata.description }}">
  <meta name="author" content="{{ metadata.author.name }}">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:url" content="{{ url or metadata.url }}">
  <meta property="og:title" content="{{ title or metadata.title }}">
  <meta property="og:description" content="{{ description or metadata.description }}">
  <meta property="og:image" content="">
  <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
  <meta property="twitter:url" content="{{ url or metadata.url }}">
  <meta property="twitter:title" content="{{ title or metadata.title }}">
  <meta property="twitter:description" content="{{ description or metadata.description }}">
  <meta property="twitter:image" content="">
  <!-- Require external JS files -->
  <script src="/js/halfmoon.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://identity.netlify.com/v1/netlify-identity-widget.js"></script>
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
  <!-- Require external CSS files -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/halfmoon.css" />
  <link href="/css/prism.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Icon -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/img/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/img/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="canonical" href="."> {% if metadata.googleAnalyticsId !== "" %}
  <!-- Google Analytics-->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={{ metadata.googleAnalyticsId }}"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', '{{ metadata.googleAnalyticsId }}');
  </script>
  {% endif %} {% if metadata.facebookPixelId !== "" %}
  <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
  <script>
    ! function(f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
      if (f.fbq) return;
      n = f.fbq = function() {
        n.callMethod ?
          n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
      };
      if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
      n.push = n;
      n.loaded = !0;
      n.version = '2.0';
      n.queue = [];
      t = b.createElement(e);
      t.async = !0;
      t.src = v;
      s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
    }(window, document, 'script',
      'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', '{your-pixel-id-goes-here}');
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
  </script>
  <noscript>
  <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" 
       src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id={your-pixel-id-goes-here}&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/>
</noscript>
  <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
  {% endif %}
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Page wrapper -->
  <div class="page-wrapper">
    <!-- Content wrapper with static navbars -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <!-- Static navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar">
        <!-- Navbar content with toggle sidebar button -->
        <div class="navbar-content">

        </div>
        <!-- Icon/brand -->
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
          <img src="{{ metadata.icon }}" alt="..." />{{ metadata.title }}
        </a>
        <!-- Navbar buttons -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav d-none d-md-flex">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="/" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="/posts" class="nav-link">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="/contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{{ metadata.feed.path | url }}" class="nav-link">RSS</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Darkmode toggle -->
        <div class="navbar-content ml-auto">
          <!-- ml-auto = margin-left: auto -->
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="halfmoon.toggleDarkMode();"></button>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <!-- Start deleting! -->
      <br>
      <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;">
        <div class="alert alert-secondary filled-dm" role="alert">
          <h4 class="alert-heading">Welcome to Rocket11ty!</h4>
          <p>It's a decent blogging platform made with Halfmoon and 11ty.</p>
          <ul>
            <li>Change the values in <code class="code">_data/metadata.json</code> to your values.</li>
            <li>If you are hosting your site on Netlify and want to enable extra features like the contact form and NetlifyCMS, enable <a href="https://docs.netlify.com/visitor-access/git-gateway/#setup-and-settings">Git Gateway</a>, <a href="https://docs.netlify.com/visitor-access/identity/">Netlify Identity</a>,
              and <a href="https://www.netlify.com/docs/form-handling/">Netlify Forms</a> (should already enabled.)</li>
            <li>Delete this message in <code class="code">includes/layouts/base.njk</code> from <code class="code">Start deleting!</code> to <code class="code">Stop deleting! Happy Blogging!</code>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <!-- Stop deleting! Happy Blogging! -->
      <!-- Content -->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        {{ content | safe }}
      </div>

      <!-- Static bottom navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-static-bottom">
        <!-- Navbar text -->
        <span class="navbar-text">
                        &copy; <div id="year">2020</div>, {{ metadata.author.name }}. All rights reserved.
                    </span>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<footer>
  <!-- Do halfmoon preferred theme -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    "light-mode" == halfmoon.getPreferredMode() || ("dark-mode" == halfmoon.getPreferredMode() || "not-set" == halfmoon.getPreferredMode() && {
      {
        metadata.defaultDarkMode
      }
    }) && halfmoon.toggleDarkMode();
  </script>
</footer>

</html>
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2):

If you have no problems on using CSS Grid, just adding this lines do the trick

```
.content-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}
```

That way the main part (.container-fluid) expands vertically as much as it can

Comment: It works to make the footer sticky but breaks the responsiveness.